# How do you calculate the probability that the sum of 100 independent random variables will be less than or equal to 215, When they are Exp(0.5)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$\xi_i\ $ has the probability frequence function:
$$f(x) = 0.5e^{-0.5x}, x\ge0$$
($\xi$ is Exp(0.5)) How do you find p($\sum_{i=1}^{100}\xi_i\le215)$
I have not real idea where to even start :( The correct awnser is approx 0.773, but how to find it?)

Comment: If you're looking for an approximate answer, the central limit theorem applies.

If you're looking for an exact answer, a sum of IID exponentials is gamma-distributed, but there isn't a nice expression for the CDF of a gamma-distributed variable.

Comment: Ten thousand thanks @MichaelLugo! For some reason, my mind had erased the central limit theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pdf is also a $\chi_{(2)}^2$ thus the sum you are looking for is a $\chi_{(200)}^2$.
You can find the exact result with a calculator or get an approx result using gaussian tables $\Phi\left(\frac{215-200}{\sqrt{400}}\right)=\Phi(0.75)\approx 0.773$